# Eigen - Create sparse matrix with the elements of a vector on the kth diagonal

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

In Eigen the `asDiagonal` function creates a diagonal matrix using a vector.
This function only places the elements of the vector on the main diagonal.

Is there a fast way to create a sparse matrix with the elements of the vector on the kth diagonal?

For exemple for dense matrices, using positive index for diagonals above the main one and negative index for the ones below, I expected:

```
 Vector3i(2,5,6).asDiagonal(-1);
```

To produce:

```
 0 0 0 0
 2 0 0 0
 0 5 0 0
 0 0 6 0
```

But `asDiagonal` takes no argument.
I know a way to do what I want, assuming that `n` is the length of the vector `vect` and `d` the diagonal index:

```
MartixXd m(n+abs(d),n+abs(d));
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   m.diagonal(d)[i] = vect(i);
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work for sparse matrices...

So I ended up with this:

```
SparseMatrix<double> m(n+abs(d),n+abs(d));
m.reserve(n);
if (d < 0)
{
   for (unsigned int l = 0; l < n; l++)
      m.coeffRef(l-d,l) = vect.coeffRef(l);
} else {
   for (unsigned int l = 0; l < n; l++)
      m.coeffRef(l,l+d) = vect.coeffRef(l);
}
```

Is there a faster and/or more elegant way to do it?

Comment: I think that this question is better suited for: scicomp.stackexchange.com